# Magic puzzle of numbers

Tags: mathematics

[image]

Send the solution as fast as possible with the way of solving it

Answer (score 6):

Simple mathematics, no  puzzle?

> ```
> 3.5 + 4.5 = 8
>  +     +
> 9.5 - 3.5 = 6
>  =     =
>  13    8
> ```